# selectRowAtIndexPath not working in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to select tableview rows programatically. I've been following the documentation and other reference here but it is not working. I don't get an error, it just do not select the rows.

Note: at the moment I am just trying to select one row manually.

Am I using the delegates, datasource and NSIndexPath correctly?

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    var myPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
    myTableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(myPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
```

[image]

Comment: When is loaded the `UITableView`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is likely that the table view is not ready or not populated at the time `viewDidLoad` is called.

Try it in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` instead:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    let myPath = NSIndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
    tableView.selectRow(at: myPath as IndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
}
```

Comment: If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `super`:

```
super.tableView(self.tableView, selectRowAtIndexPath: myPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the UITableView method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. It should work better than in the viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with `UITableViewScrollPositionNone` if view is not currently visible and during `viewDidLoad`/`viewWillAppear` it's still not.
You can use `UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle` to scroll to some cell in this case.